# Using batchscript to create for exercise blank/empty templates html & css

Tags: batch-file

I  created empty  templates html & css for exercise using batchscript  and external text file named folders.txt  .
Folder.txt is external text file working folder for generating folders from 1 to 10 and inside each of that folders are to be corresponding files named : 1.html &  1.css ,2.html &  2.css...  ...10.html &  10.css
Problem  is that symbols marks for opening and closing html tags consists  < , >  in batscript those marks are as control characters and can't be use to generate echo line  in batchscript  .
Instead of that can be used one of solution corresponding substitute marks to be replaced : by CTRL+H
for opening mark < can be  [,
for closing marks > can be ],
How to make more easier to get direct result if possible?

Comment: Escape your characters: `^<` and `^>`

Comment: That what I wanted to have  to make an easier  job -Many  thanks  !!!                                ......................                                                                                           echo  ^<!doctype html^>  >%%a\%%a.html"                                                                                                         echo  ^<html lang="en"^>  >>%%a\%%a.html"  .